# NodeJS fs.unlinkSync not freeing up hard-drive space on aws ec2 server

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS application on Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm downloading a large number of large zips, opening and processing them, then deleting the zip files via `fs.unlinkSync`

When testing I see the files get deleted, but apparently unlink won't actually deallocate the space while a process is using it?

How can I instruct fs to free up the memory allocation?

I am writing the file via

```
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.name);
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
  // a bunch of logic that eventually returns a promise
```

and inside its resolve/reject

```
fs.unlinkSync(file.name)
```

I've gone through and those are the only times I'm touching the file, everything else is closed. Is there some other event I need to wait for for the writeStream to close?

-- to fully explain the workflow

```
for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  await processZip(records[i]);
  fs.unlinkSync(records[i].name);
}
```

inside the processZip method

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  var readStream = this.s3Access.getObjectStream(guid);
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.name);
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);

  writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    resolve();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to let the gc do it's work. Use [`nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args) and make sure you let go of variables that contain the memory

Answer (score 3):

According to [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path) `unlinkSync()` is calling C/C++ API call `unlink`.

Here is what docs says [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)

> unlink() deletes a name from the filesystem.  If that name was the
> last link to a file and no processes have the file open, the file is
> deleted and the space it was using is made available for reuse.
>
> If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still have
> the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file
> descriptor referring to it is closed.
>
> If the name referred to a symbolic link, the link is removed.
>
> If the name referred to a socket, FIFO, or device, the name for it is
> removed but processes which have the object open may continue to use
> it.

Basically all links should be closed for a file to be deleted.

Try to think of other processes that may use the files you are trying to delete (files opened with `fs.open/openSync()` which were not closed etc.)

**UPDATED**

It looks like the file is deleted after the promise returned by `processZip` is resolved successfully.

It would be useful to also delete the file if the promise was rejected (i.e. error thrown in async function).

```
for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  try {
    await processZip(records[i]);
  } finally {
    // delete file after success or error
    fs.unlinkSync(records[i].name);
  }
}
```

Additionally `'error'` event handlers can be added to both streams in `processZip`.

I've found this note in `stream.pipe()` [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options), maybe it's related to the issue:

> One important caveat is that if the `Readable` stream emits an error during processing, the `Writable` destination is not closed automatically. If an error occurs, it will be necessary to manually close each stream in order to prevent memory leaks.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  var readStream = this.s3Access.getObjectStream(guid);
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.name);
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);

  writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    resolve();
  }

  readStream.on('error', err => {
    readStream.end();
    writeStream.end();
    reject(err);
  }

  writeStream.on('error', err => {
    readStream.end();
    writeStream.end();
    reject(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vitalii thanks for the suggestion, I went through and ensured no other links or refs to the file, and updated my question to show

Comment: Hi Joshua, I've found extra info in docs regarding error handling and added a suggestion for error handling for your code in my response.